# Change MySQL time zone without super permissions

Tags: php, mysql, apache, timezone

I added this line to my config.inc.php file.

```
$query = "SET SESSION time_zone = 'Europe/Rome'";
if (mysql_query($query, DB_LINK) == FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error(DB_LINK));
}
```

It doesn't give me any error, but when I use the `NOW()` or the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` function it saves the record with a wrong time.

How can I set the date time zone in MySQL without the super permissions?

Comment: What if you specify the time offset with time `+01:00`?

Comment: @zerkms thanks for answering, but it does not work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using 5.5, if you see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html, it says:

`mysql> SET time_zone = timezone;`

It also says:

```
The current session time zone setting affects display and storage of time values that are zone-sensitive. This includes the values displayed by functions such as NOW() or CURTIME(), and values stored in and retrieved from TIMESTAMP columns. Values for TIMESTAMP columns are converted from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval.

The current time zone setting does not affect values displayed by functions such as UTC_TIMESTAMP() or values in DATE, TIME, or DATETIME columns. Nor are values in those data types stored in UTC; the time zone applies for them only when converting from TIMESTAMP values. If you want locale-specific arithmetic for DATE, TIME, or DATETIME values, convert them to UTC, perform the arithmetic, and then convert back.
```

So try it without the `SESSION` and see if it works, and also check that `select @@session.time_zone;`
 gives you the right timezone.

EDIT: you may just have an issue with your database. I just tried this on one of my databases (5.5.8) and it worked, but it failed on 5.0.51. So you may need a db upgrade.

```
mysql> select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
+---------------------+
| CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() |
+---------------------+
| 2011-05-29 14:33:06 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> set time_zone = 'Europe/Rome';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
+---------------------+
| CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() |
+---------------------+
| 2011-05-29 16:33:11 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 5.5.8-log |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It set correctly the MySQL time zone, but it keep doesn't work for the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() function.

Comment: @Aegidius: copy-paste us please the mysql console sample with your queries. Everything should work fine

Comment: Thanks for the answer. CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() -> 2011-05-29 07:53:04 - SET time_zone =  'Europe/Rome' -> 0 rows - CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() -> 2011-05-29 07:55:04 - version() -> 5.0.91-log ... :(

Comment: Yep, didn't work right on the 5.0 series. I think you are out of luck. You might want to look at using the http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz functions.

Comment: I really thank you, for helping me. I just removed all the MySQL function and replaced them with PHP function. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Erm I'm not sure how to set time zone with mysql...

but i prefer to set the time zone with php...

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');
```